# Highlight a single visual line within a physical line

Tags: highlighting, visual-line-mode

I want to have a single line in a long-word wrapped line highlighted. The default setting of hl-line seems to highlight the whole wrapped line as shown below.

[image]

Which setting do I have to change to highlight only the line in which the cursor is located in a longer wrapped line? In the screenshot this would be the first line of the text.

Comment: It is not a great idea, though not strictly forbidden, to cross-post the same question to both [StackOverflow, tag emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31541907/729907) and this site. Since you have already gotten answers there, consider deleting your question here.

Comment: There is a prior thread on stackoverflow.com that already contains an answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275596/how-to-use-hl-line-mode-to-highlight-just-one-1-line-when-visual-line-mode-is

Comment: Sorry, for double posting. Was my first question asked ever, and I did not find the answer on stackoverflow. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this in my init.el for a while:

```lisp
(defun highlight-visual-line ()
  (save-excursion
    (cons (progn (beginning-of-visual-line) (point))
          (progn (end-of-visual-line) (point)))))

(setq hl-line-range-function 'highlight-visual-line)
```

This is assuming you use `(global-hl-line-mode 1)` to achieve that highlighting. I probably posted this as an answer either in this forum, or in SO section for Emacs questions, but cannot find it at the moment.